# Custom Error Pages in Rails + Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I want to render the error pages on my rails app by following [this post](https://medium.com/@tair/custom-error-pages-in-rails-you-re-doing-it-wrong-ba1d20ec31c0#.fp7u6zr1o) but change it to work with Heroku.

Post stack: Rails + Nginx + Capistrano.
My stack:   Rails + Heroku.

`my-app.herokuapp.com/assets/XXX.html` URL is working but I need to render `my-app.herokuapp.com/XXX.html`

I think I need to change the following code, taken from the post, to work with Heroku!

```
root /myapp/current/public;
error_page 404 /404.html;
location /404.html {
  internal;
  root /myapp/current/public/assets;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Heroku is completely different to the original post you are following:

Every other error your app is going to serve 404, 422 and 500 from the html files in the *public/* directory in your app by default.

For 503 errors you need to set the `ERROR_PAGE_URL` environment variable that points to the static page you want to server when an error occurs:

```
heroku config:set ERROR_PAGE_URL=//s3.amazonaws.com/<your_bucket>/your_error_page.html
```

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-pages#configure-your-application for other customizations.

Comment: thanks but not the heroku's custom error page isn't displayed whenever an exception occurs in rails application.
The error page happens when an error occurs with heroku. I want handle errors of my rails app.

Comment: You are right, I've updated my answer to include how to customize the error messages for 404, 422 and 500 errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

I did that feature few days ago, and I found that article which the most clear and useful https://thepugautomatic.com/2014/08/404-with-rails-4/

But if you want handle 500 error or another you should add one more string in routes and in 'CustomPublicExceptions' add condition to status

Comment: Thanks if I cannot find out a solution I will give a chance to this.
But my idea is not use Rails stuff(controller) to render errors if the app crashes